# Is it safe to not specify a destructor in a subclass of a base class with a virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider a simple interface/implementation design:

```
class Base
{
public:

    virtual ~Base()
    {
        // Virtual empty destructor
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:

    virtual ~Derived()
    {
        // Lots of clean up code here
        // ...
    }
};
```

With this design, I understand that the following code is safe and valid:

```
Base* base = new Derived();
delete base; // Both Base::~Base and Derived::~Derived get called
```

However, imagine if there was a new class:

```
class DerivedEx : public Derived
{
public:

    // No destructor here, relying on default destructor generated by compiler
};
```

Is **DerivedEx** "safe"?

For safety, I always assumed that I'd have to implement a virtual empty destructor in **DerivedEx**. But I'm wondering if this is redundant and unnecessary and whether or not there are any 'gotchas' that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's still safe.

A destructor is automatically virtual if any base class destructor is virtual.  This is true whether you type `~Foo();` or `virtual ~Foo();` or neither and just allow the compiler to generate the implicitly defined destructor.

Comment: So you mean the `virtual` for `Derived::~Derived` would be redundant as well?

Comment: @Farbod T. It's redundant only to the compiler. To your future human maintainers it's a lifesaver to understand what the program is doing.

Answer (score 4):

It is safe. You just need to ensure that the destructor in the base class is `virtual`.
As long as your Base class destructor is `virtual` the compiler will take care of calling all the destructors in the correct order.

Whether you need a destructor in most derived class depends on that class itself & that decision is usually made based on ***[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)***.

Comment: I'd remove the starting "No" from your answer, as the question stands "Is DerivedEx safe?"

Comment: @Angew: Thanks. I guess my *"No"* was a result of my mind shouting No! no it is not required, when I had just reached that point in the question :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is safe.

The implicitly generated destructor will be virtual, since there is a base class with a virtual destructor, and will correctly call the destructors of all non-trivial members and base classes.